# How to send attachment in Google Appscripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add an attachment from a Google Drive folder. But I am getting an error, I have referred to various questions related to this topic as well, but have failed to find a solution.
Can someone please help?
Attaching Screenshot of the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuDnk.png)

Comment: `DriveApp.getFilesByName()` does not return a file it returns a file iterator.  You could get the first file  by using `DriveApp.getFilesByName().next()`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type

Comment: So that folder has various files, how do I select a particular file if I do not enter the name?

Comment: Hey! I think I have the solution thanks to the link you shared, let me check it out and get back,

Comment: In Google Drive files can have the same name and the primary way of differentiating files is the id.